# Проблема с передачей переменной в sqlite3-запрос

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

```
def addword():
    global wordInput
    connection = sqlite3.connect('wordDict.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO verbs(Infinitive)
                    VALUES (wordInput)''')
    connection.commit()
```

Это часть моего кода, в sql-запрос я хочу передать переменную, но выдаёт ошибку:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: wordInput

f-строки не сработали

Comment: Напишите вот так: `'wordInput'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка очевидная - сервер SQLite не знает ничего про переменную *wordInput*, вот и ругается. На самом деле, на месте этой переменной в SQL запросе должна стоять текстовая константа, являющаяся **значением** этой переменной! Попробуйте как-то так:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO verbs(Infinitive) VALUES ('%s')" % wordInput)
```

Comment: Я поставил минус, так как у такого решения серьезная [проблема с безопасностью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), а именно проблема с внедрением SQL-кода.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, но, поскольку программа только для меня, взламывать будет нечего :)

Comment: Тут программа для вас, а придет другой человек, воспользуется ответом и вставит этот код в свою программу и начнутся [реальные проблемы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Examples) начиная с кражи учетных записей и заканчивая кражей кредиток.

Comment: @RomanKonoval - "проблема с внедрением SQL-кода."
- Не могли бы Вы уточнить - давно SQLite стали использовать на HTTP серверах?

Comment: Это не так важно. Код часто перекочевывает из проекта в проект. Сегодня sqlite, а завтра - postgres. Зачем учить плохим практикам? Манипуляции со строками для sql запросов - плохая практика. Даже без sql injection в этом коде есть проблема с экранированием кавычек. Как минимум в ответ нужно написать, что это плохая практика. Тогда ответ будет полезен автору для узкой задачи, но не будет распостранять плохие подходы.

Comment: @RomanKonoval - " в ответ нужно написать"
- Ну так **напишите**!